# Center Align UL for 2 lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align my menu that goes onto 2 lines.

I'm using ul li. not sure if this is the best option. I've trued everything from posts posted on SO, but nothing doing :(

**I would like it to go onto 2 lines and still be centered**

Here is s screen shot of what it looks like:

[image: Menu]

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 480px) {
.header-links-mobile {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%;
  position:absolute;
  top:60px;
  left:0%;
  text-align:center;
}

.header-links-mobile ul {
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-links-mobile ul li { 
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px 5px 0 5px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-links-mobile ul li a { 
  color:#fff;
}

.header-links-mobile ul li a:hover {
  color:#fff;
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-links-mobile">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/mass-supply-live/Admin" class="administration">Admin Panel</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/mass-supply-live/order/history" class="account">asheenk@cyphernet.co.za</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/mass-supply-live/logout" class="ico-logout">Log out</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ico-account-wrapper">
      <a href="/mass-supply-live/customer/spend-meter" class="ico-logout">My account</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/mass-supply-live/cart" class="ico-cart" id="topcartlink">
        <span class="cart-label">Shopping cart</span>
        <span class="cart-qty">(54 ITEM)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: share html code!

Comment: Sorry. Code shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following style

```
.header-links-mobile, .header-links-mobile ul {
    width :100%;
}


.header-links-mobile ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c14hndn/3/)

Comment: When I do that it goes onto 1 line and still not centered. I want it to go onto 2 lines and be centered.

Comment: Ok ...In which screen resolution do you want that ?

Comment: I'm adding the media query to the question now.